# Fatal Error, setActive = setActiveMenu appears right, erroring out

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, magento2-enterprise

Magento 2.1 EE

I'm getting a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on
>   boolean

This is in:

`vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php on line 13`

It happens when I try to do:

```
$this->_setActiveMenu($this->_activeMenu);
```

My controller code:

```
<?php

namespace Wundercarparts\Makeanoffer\Controller\Adminhtml;

/**
 * Abstract admin controller
 */
abstract class Actions extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Form session key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_formSessionKey;

    /**
     * Allowed Key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_allowedKey;

    /**
     * Model class name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_modelClass;

    /**
     * Active menu key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_activeMenu;

    /**
     * Store config section key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_configSection;

    /**
     * Request id key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Status field name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_statusField     = 'status';

    /**
     * Save request params key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_paramsHolder;

    /**
     * Model Object
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
     */
    protected $_model;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Action execute
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $_preparedActions = array('index', 'grid', 'new', 'edit', 'save', 'delete', 'config', 'massStatus');
        $_action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        if (in_array($_action, $_preparedActions)) {
            $method = '_'.$_action.'Action';

            $this->_beforeAction();
            $this->$method();
            $this->_afterAction();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _indexAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax')) {
            $this->_forward('grid');
            return;
        }

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu($this->_activeMenu);
        $title = __('Manage '.$this->_getModel(false)->getOwnTitle(true));
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($title);
        $this->_addBreadcrumb($title, $title);
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Grid action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _gridAction()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout(false);
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * New action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    /**
     * Edit action
     * @return void
     */
    public function _editAction()
    {
        $model = $this->_getModel();

        $this->_getRegistry()->register('current_model', $model);

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu($this->_activeMenu);

        $title = $model->getOwnTitle();

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $breadcrumbTitle = __('Edit '.$title);
            $breadcrumbLabel = $breadcrumbTitle;
        } else {
            $breadcrumbTitle = __('New '.$title);
            $breadcrumbLabel = __('Create '.$title);
        }
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__($title));
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(
            $model->getId() ? $this->_getModelName($model) : __('New '.$title)
        );

        $this->_addBreadcrumb($breadcrumbLabel, $breadcrumbTitle);

        // restore data
        $values = $this->_getSession()->getData($this->_formSessionKey, true);
        if ($this->_paramsHolder) {
            $values = isset($values[$this->_paramsHolder]) ? $values[$this->_paramsHolder] : null;
        }

        if ($values) {
            $model->addData($values);
        }

        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve model name
     * @param  boolean $plural
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getModelName(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {
        return $model->getName() ?: $model->getTitle();
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     * @return void
     */
    public function _saveAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (!$request->isPost()) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl('*/*'));
        }
        $model = $this->_getModel();

        try {
            $params = $this->_paramsHolder ? $request->getParam($this->_paramsHolder) : $request->getParams();
            $model->addData($params);

            $this->_beforeSave($model, $request);
            $model->save();
            $this->_afterSave($model, $request);

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__($model->getOwnTitle().' has been saved.'));
            $this->_setFormData(false);

            if ($request->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', [$this->_idKey => $model->getId()]);
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*');
            }
            return;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(nl2br($e->getMessage()));
            $this->_setFormData();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving this '.strtolower($model->getOwnTitle()).'.').' '.$e->getMessage());
            $this->_setFormData();
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', [$this->_idKey => $model->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * Before model Save action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _beforeSave($model, $request) {}

    /**
     * After model action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _afterSave($model, $request) {}

    /**
     * Before action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _beforeAction() {}

    /**
     * After action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _afterAction() {}

    /**
     * Delete action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _deleteAction()
    {
        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->_idKey);

        if (!is_array($ids)) {
            $ids = [$ids];
        }

        $error = false;
        try {
            foreach($ids as $id) {
                $this->_objectManager->create($this->_modelClass)->setId($id)->delete();
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $error = true;
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $error = true;
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t delete '.strtolower($this->_getModel(false)->getOwnTitle()).' right now. '.$e->getMessage()));
        }

        if (!$error) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __($this->_getModel(false)->getOwnTitle(count($ids) > 1).' have been deleted.')
            );
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    /**
     * Change status action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _massStatusAction()
    {
        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->_idKey);

        if (!is_array($ids)) {
            $ids = [$ids];
        }

        $model = $this->_getModel(false);

        $error = false;

        try {

            $status = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
            $statusFieldName = $this->_statusField;

            if (is_null($status)) {
                throw new \Exception(__('Parameter "Status" missing in request data.'));
            }

            if (is_null($statusFieldName)) {
                throw new \Exception(__('Status Field Name is not specified.'));
            }

            foreach($ids as $id) {
                $this->_objectManager->create($this->_modelClass)
                    ->load($id)
                    ->setData($this->_statusField, $status)
                    ->save();
            }

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $error = true;
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $error = true;
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t change status of '.strtolower($model->getOwnTitle()).' right now. '.$e->getMessage()));
        }

        if (!$error) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __($model->getOwnTitle(count($ids) > 1).' status have been changed.')
            );
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*');

    }

    /**
     * Go to config section action
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _configAction()
    {
        $this->_redirect('admin/system_config/edit', ['section' => $this->_configSection()]);
    }

    /**
     * Set form data
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _setFormData($data = null)
    {
        $this->_getSession()->setData($this->_formSessionKey,
            is_null($data) ? $this->getRequest()->getParams() : $data);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get core registry
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _getRegistry()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_coreRegistry)) {
            $this->_coreRegistry = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
        }
        return $this->_coreRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Check is allowed access
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($this->_allowedKey);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve model object
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
     */
    protected function _getModel($load = true)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_model)) {
            $this->_model = $this->_objectManager->create($this->_modelClass);

            $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam($this->_idKey);
            if ($id && $load) {
                $this->_model->load($id);
            }
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }

}
```

This is a controller.  I set activeMenu to:

```
Magento_Sales::sales_order
```

I am obviously missing something.  I've tried comparing this code to other modules and core modules.  Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no block with the name "menu" in your layout.
The `_setActiveMenu` method looks like this:

```
protected function _setActiveMenu($itemId)
{
    /** @var $menuBlock \Magento\Backend\Block\Menu */
    $menuBlock = $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('menu');
    $menuBlock->setActive($itemId);
    $parents = $menuBlock->getMenuModel()->getParentItems($itemId);
    foreach ($parents as $item) {
        /** @var $item \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Item */
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($item->getTitle());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The problem is that `$menuBlock = $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('menu');` returns false and then it tries to call false->setActive().

This can happen because the layout handle that is loaded for your controller does not contain the `menu` block.
Make sure that the layout file exists and it contains this attribute `layout="admin-1column"` on the main `<page>` tag.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- content here -->
</page>
```

Side note:
You are using your controller in a wrong way.
You are adding all the actions in the same file and in `execute` you just dispatch the responsibility to one of the methods.
This makes the code hard to debug and hard to maintain.
I strongly recommend using the Magento 2 way of doing MVC, with one controller action per class / file.

Comment: After try this error solved, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/246115/57334 is it recommended? @Marius♦

Answer (score 0):

Your code lines should work. Try to clear Magento Cache and make sure your custom controller extends from `Magento\Backend\App\Action` class.

We may need to remove `$this->_getModel(false)` and set the active menu:`$this->_setActiveMenu('Magento_Sales::sales_order');`. For example for index action:

```
/**
 * Index action
 * @return void
 */
protected function _indexAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax')) {
        $this->_forward('grid');
        return;
    }

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('Magento_Sales::sales_order');
    // $title = __('Manage '.$this->_getModel(false)->getOwnTitle(true)); <= Should change this
    $title = __('Testing Testing');
    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($title);
    $this->_addBreadcrumb($title, $title);
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Hi, that didn't do the trick.  I'm extending that already.  I did make the change you suggested above, but the error remains.  I also did a var_dump to be sure that I'm sending the right thing through: "/var/www/wundercarparts/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:136:string 'Magento_Sales::sales_order' (length=26)"  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DanJoseph you can update your question with the full code lines?

Comment: Done.  Let me know if you need more code from other files.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... this just wasn't working at all, so I "started fresh".  I suspect I had some layout issues somewhere.  I redid things and have a working page with a basic grid.  Thanks for the help.