# Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:27

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am using a module which gives me this error when I try to open its settings in the admin.

This is part of the stack trace:

> app/code/Rokanthemes/SlideBanner/Controller/Adminhtml/Slider/Index.php(70):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Rokanthemes_Sli...')

Code of controller: https://pastebin.com/wVrQ6QcE

I can see that it tries to set the menu for **Rokanthemes_Slidebanner** which is of course the extension I am talking about. The question is, why it cant set the menu for that single extension while the rest works just fine. I have no idea where to look anymore.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: can you post the full controller in here?

Comment: Sure, updated my post

Comment: strange. The controller looks ok. For some reason `$this->layout->getBlock('menu')` returns false in this case.

Comment: Yes, but why, maybe its related to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222174/reflectionexception-class-does-not-exist?

Comment: are you sure that your extension files are readable?

Comment: I solved it by uploading the latest version of the extension. THANKS for your time @Marius!

Comment: I encountered this problem recently and it turned out to be a section of my acl.xml causing the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, it is a [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13504). Deleting `generated/metadata/global.php` may solve it.

Comment: Thanks @dani-garval, it work for me. facing this problem from long time.