# ReflectionException: Class does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am running into this error when compiling:

> [ReflectionException] Class
>   \Rokanthemes\SlideBanner\Api\SlideRepositoryInterface does not exist

I checked and of course that class exists. Here is the content of the class: https://pastebin.com/LVxZgeqM

> Stack Trace:
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:177 
>   ReflectionClass->__construct() at
>   /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:177 
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->collectEntities() at
>   /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php:77
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\ApplicationCodeGenerator->doOperation()
>   at /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56 
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at
>   /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:205 
>   Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at
>   /vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104 
>   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at
>   /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /bin/magento:23
>
> setup:di:compile

After removing the extension compilation goes through without problems. It worked in 2.1, after upgrading to 2.2.3 I am running into this error. Any idea what might go wrong?

I am using PHP 7.0.29

Thanks!

Comment: How you checked if theres no spelling errors?

Comment: Yeah, it worked in 2.1, it started in 2.2.3 so I guess its somehow related to that update.

Comment: I solved it by uploading the latest version of the extension